# qmake doesn't add libraries from .pro file to the makefile

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, qmake

I try to build an QT project using qmake. For this I need the boost library.

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/ \
 -lboost_system \
 -lboost_filesystem
```

But after running qmake, these libraries are not added to the makefile:

```
LIBS = $(SUBLIBS) -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQt5MultimediaWidgets
-L/build/buildd/qtmultimedia-opensource-src-5.0.1/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5OpenGL -lQt5Multimedia -lpulse
-lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread
```

As expected, the linker prints many error like

```
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: error: undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()
```

If you want to take a look to the whole .pro file, go to https://raw.github.com/francisengelmann/FabScan100/master/qtTest/qtTest.pro

I am also having a similar problem with opencv. Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference but you have some lines repeated in the .pro file.

Comment: I did also recognize this, but as you say, deleting these multiple lines doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your build folder entirely and re-building the project?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the folder and ran "build project" in qt creator, but the errors are the same.

Comment: Which version of qmake are you using?  I ran your project file through qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.1.1) on Mac OS X, and I'm not able to reproduce the problem here — `Makefile`'s `LIBS` includes OpenCV and Boost and Point Cloud Library, as expected.

Comment: Do you see the message produced by `message("Building for Linux.")` statement when running qmake?

Comment: Thank you very much for you advices, this is a school project so im not able to look these thinks up now. Im going to set up a build enviroment at home but I will need a few days. I'll post those things when this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `qmake` again after changing the `.pro` file. Just removing your build directory is not enough.

Also are you sure your qmake target is linux-g++? Does the INCLUDEPATH work?

Comment: I did run qmake after that. Look for my comment on the other answer, I'll test those things when I have a build enviroment at home.

Comment: Check the spec your qmake is using. If you're on a 64-bit system, most likely you'd need a spec of linux-g++* (with the star). Or just use linux-* spec, as your headers and libs are not gcc-specific.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the problem. My qmake target was linux-g++64. With linux-g++ it works great. Thank you.