# Why doesn't qmake include library files?

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to link a third party library to my Qt project. Here is my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = camera_ui

QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl --enable-new-dtags -Wl -rpath /opt/pylon5/lib64
INCLUDEPATH += -I/opt/pylon5/include

LIBS += -L/opt/pylon5/lib64 -Wl -E \
       -lpylonbase \
       -lpylonutility \
       -lGenApi_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0 \
       -lGCBase_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0 \
       -lopencv_core \
       -lopencv_highgui

# Input
HEADERS += basler_opencv_utils.h camera_interface.h mainwindow.h
FORMS += mainwindow.ui
SOURCES += basler_opencv_utils.cc main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
```

But here is the output after running `qmake` then `make`.

```
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I-I/opt/pylon5/include -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o basler_opencv_utils.o basler_opencv_utils.cc
basler_opencv_utils.cc:5:33: fatal error: pylon/PylonIncludes.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:373: recipe for target 'basler_opencv_utils.o' failed
make: *** [basler_opencv_utils.o] Error 1
```

Notice that the INCLUDE_PATH works, but the LIBS and QMAKE_LFLAGS are not included in the build command. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496908/qmake-doesnt-add-libraries-from-pro-file-to-the-makefile?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742856/qt-creator-adding-external-library-still-cannot-open-include-file-gl-glew-h/16747255) but those didn't solve my problem. I've also tried adding `TARGETDEPS += libpylonbase.so` as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781494/how-do-a-specify-a-library-file-dependency-for-qmake-in-qt), with no change.

I also tried using Qt Creator to make the .pro file for my, but I couldn't figure out what I was supposed to enter into the wizard in the "library files" field.

**UPDATE:** I was able to get it working with some help from the section below. If anyone else is trying to use the Basler Pylon SDK with QT5 here is a working make file (includes OpenCV as well).

```
QT += core gui widgets

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = camera_ui
PYLON_ROOT = /opt/pylon5
# Input
HEADERS += basler_opencv_utils.h camera_interface.h mainwindow.h
FORMS += mainwindow.ui
SOURCES += basler_opencv_utils.cc main.cpp mainwindow.cpp

QMAKE_CPPFLAGS += /opt/pylon5/include
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH += -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/opt/pylon5/lib64

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/pylon5/include
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/pylon5/lib64

LIBS += /opt/pylon5/lib64 -Wl,-E -lpylonbase -lpylonutility -lGenApi_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0 -lGCBase_gcc_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0
LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, your `INCLUDEPATH` doesn't work. Your include is `INCLUDEPATH += -I/opt/pylon5/include` which resolves to `-I-I/opt/pylon5/include` correct (`-I/opt/pylon5/include`) and that is an invalid directory. `-I` must be removed from `INCLUDEPATH`. The header file `PylonIncludes.h` is expected to be in`/opt/pylon5/include/pylon/PylonIncludes.h`
2. The correct path to include a library is

   `LIBS += -L"/home/directory" -lmylibrary -mylibrary2` - If the library is not found, the compiler throws an error.

   `LIBS += -L/opt/pylon5/lib64 -Wl -E \` is invalid and truncates probably the libraries after `-WL -E \`
3. You  linker flags: `QMAKE_LDFLAGS` is correct. `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl` etc. Why you don't see it in the g++ command line? It's the compiler not the linker, you error out before.